# How to save readonly property value in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have a custom class:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class CustomClass
{
    public int State { get; set; }
}
```

A readonly property:

```
public class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public CustomClass MyProperty { get; } = new CustomClass();
}
```

The property is shown and editable in the properties window.

[image: PropertyGrid]

**But the value is not saved**, if reopen the designer, it's restored.

I think it's not hard for designer to generate code like:

```
myControl.MyProperty.State = 1;
```

How to make the readonly property savable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days searching I find a solution, very simple:

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public CustomClass MyProperty { get; } = new CustomClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use two different properties with backing field. Check my answer below with `ReadOnly` Attribute

```
[ReadOnly(true)]
public int ReadOnlyStateProp
{
    get
    {
        return _ReadOnlyState;
    }
    set
    {
        _ReadOnlyState = value;
    }
}

public int ReadOnlyState
{
    get
    {
        return _ReadOnlyState;
    }
    set
    {
        _ReadOnlyState = value;
    }
}
```

now you can use `ReadOnlyStateProp` for property window and `ReadOnlyState` 
in editable context.

Comment: If I put `ReadOnlyAttribute` on `State` property, it's not editable any more. If I put it on `MyProperty` property, nothing changes. I want the readonly property editable in properties window, so your answer is not helpful.

Comment: Sorry there may have some fault in my description, what I mean for readonly property is a property only has get accessor like `MyProperty` in the post. I want the property `State` in `MyProperty` both editable and savable in the properties window.